# Showing that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(\log x)^\alpha}{x^\beta}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

> If $\alpha ,\beta\in\mathbb{R}^+$, show that $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(\log x)^\alpha}{x^\beta}=0$$

**My attempt:**

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(\log x)^\alpha}{x^\beta}= \displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left[\frac{(\log x)}{x^{\beta /\alpha}}\right]^\alpha$.

Since the function $y=z^\alpha$ is continuous, then $$ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left[\frac{(\log x)}{x^{\beta /\alpha}}\right]^\alpha=\left[\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(\log x)}{x^{\beta /\alpha}}\right]^\alpha$$ Let $\eta=\beta/\alpha$. Applying L'Hôpital's rule

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(\log x)}{x^{\eta}}=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\eta x^{\eta -1}}=\frac{1}{\eta}\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\eta}}=\frac{1}{\eta}*0=0$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: I would say it is,